# What does the second antiderivative of a function represent?

Tags: calculus

If the antiderivative represents the area under the curve from $f(0)$ to $f(x)$ what does the second antiderivative or the antiderivative of the antiderivative represent?

Comment: Sarcastically speaking the area under the curve of the anti derivative, but great question.

Comment: @Sigma6RPU wow thank you I'm really not sure why it was so hard to wrap my head around that

Comment: I was joking of course, and being serious. But for real great question.

Comment: wait so that's not actually what it represents?

Comment: It's a joke because it's trivial and unenlightening.

Comment: $\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$ is the area under the curve from $0$ to $x.$

Comment: Assuming you have some initial conditions and if $f$ represents the acceleration of a particular over time, then the second antiderivative will give you the position of the particle over time. You can extend this idea to the "acceleration" of any quantity with respect to time or any other quantity.

Comment: The second integral could be thought about the same way in terms of  physical changing quantities.  Basically you are asking what the position function means in retrospect to acceleration.

Comment: But yes what I meant before is correct it is the area underneath the first integral.

Comment: You could also imagine the second antiderivative to represent "extruding" the area represented by the first antiderivative into a solid.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) suggests It should be “an” rather than “the antiderivative”, as there are many; $f(0)$ is not assumed as a string point — but maybe the usage varies.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the premise "If the antiderivative represents the area under the curve from $f(0)$ to $f(x)$" is iffy: A function $f$ having one antiderivative has infinitely many (as PJTaill says), so one can't speak of *the* antiderivative. (If the domain is an interval, any two antiderivatives differ by a constant. If the domain is disconnected, there can be "independent constants in each component.")

Second, "the area under the curve from $f(0)$ to $f(x)$" presumably refers (as zhw notes) to the portion of the fundamental theorem of calculus guaranteeing that if $f$ is *continuous* on an interval containing $0$ and $x$, the function
$$
F_{1}(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)\, dt
$$
is an antiderivative of $f$. The identification of $F_{1}(x)$ with a certain area is arguably more of an *interpretation* than an *identification*, however. (Separately, as a fine point, if $f$ has a jump discontinuity at $x$, the function $F_{1}$ is not an antiderivative of $f$ at $x$, and in fact *no* function is an antiderivative of $f$ at $x$. This is not a trivial nitpick: An integrable function can have a jump discontinuity at each rational number, for example.)

The comments of Sigma6RPU and Anthony D'Arienzo note that the second antiderivative may similarly be *interpreted* as the volume of the solid obtained by extruding the area under the graph $y = f(x)$. Analytically, put
$$
F_{2}(x)
  = \int_{0}^{x} F_{1}(s)\, ds
  = \int_{0}^{x} \int_{0}^{s} f(t)\, dt\, ds
  = \int_{0}^{x} \int_{t}^{x} f(t)\, ds\, dt
  = \int_{0}^{x} (x - t) f(t)\, dt.
$$
[image: A second antiderivative as the volume of an extruded region]

In case it's of interest, the preceding iterated formula generalizes (compare with the [integral form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) of the remainder in Taylor's theorem) to
$$
F_{n}(x) = \frac{1}{(n - 1)!} \int_{0}^{x} (x - t)^{n-1} f(t)\, dt,
$$
whose $n$th derivative is easily checked to be $f$, provided $f$ is continuous. The value $F_{n}(x)$ can be interpreted geometrically as an $(n + 1)$-dimensional volume obtained by "successive extrusion", but is probably best regarded analytically.

If you're seeking a physical interpretation along the lines of [What does the integral of position with respect to time mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637409), beware that the question is deeper than it naively appears.